# Selection algorithm on depth-$\text{O}(\log n)$ sorting network

Tags: dc.parallel-comp, sorting, sorting-network

Is there a sorting network of depth $\text{O}(\log n)$ for selecting the $i$th order statistic?

Remark: I've already asked a related question in a [different context](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/6642/hans-on-log-log-n-time-linear-space-integer-sorting-algorithm).  Although the two questions are related, this is not a duplicate of the other one.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_network#Optimal_sorting

Comment: Well, well, who would've thunk it possible?  (You can tell I'm not well versed in sorting networks.)  Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can construct selection networks of depth O(log n) using graph expanders or using variants of the AKS sorting network.

S. Jimbo and A. Maruoka, A Method of Constructing Selection Networks with $O(\log n)$ Depth,SIAM J. Comput. 25, pp. 709-739, http://dx.doi.org/10.1137/S0097539793248329

Comment: Jimbo and Maruoka only do median (as far as I can tell from the abstract+intro).  However AKS/Paterson actually sort, so obviously can do selection too.

Comment: It should be easy to reduce to median, by adding extra elements (and it can be done in parallel).